# Docker: Cannot connect to other container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, docker-network

[image: ![image|690x402](upload://nU943fLQhXqbw3DkuXC2qfP373c.png)]

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  wp-assets:

services:
  mariadb:
    build: ./requirements/mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
      - "127.0.0.1:9999:9999" # test

  wordpress:
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
      - WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY=${WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY}
      - WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY=${WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY}
      - WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY=${WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY}
      - WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY=${WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY}
      - WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT=${WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT}
      - WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT=${WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT}
      - WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT=${WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT}
      - WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT=${WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT}
    volumes:
      - wp-assets:/var/wp-assets
    build: ./requirements/wordpress
    ports:
      # host_port == 127.0.0.1:9000, allow only localhost
      - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"

  nginx:
    #    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on: 
      - wordpress
    volumes:
      - wp-assets:/var/wp-assets
    build: ./requirements/nginx
    ports:
      # host_port == 0.0.0.0:8080, allow all interfaces
      - "8080:80"
```

`mariadb/Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:buster

# install mariadb-server
RUN apt update && apt install -y mariadb-server

# allow connection from wordpress (host name)
RUN sed -e 's/127.0.0.1/wordpress/' \
        -i '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf'

# used for socket
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld && \
    chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld && \ 
    touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# init db here

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

#ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f"]
```

I was trying to connect `mariadb` with `wordpress (mariadb-client)`, and got an error :
`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb'`

So I tested ports are good. But while other ports like `nginx:80` or `wordpress:9000` can be accessed by the other containers, ports of `mariadb` refuses connections.

I couldn't figure out what is difference between `mariadb` container and the others. What's the problem?

Comment: does telnet fail with port 3306 ?

Comment: Why don't you use `mariadb` image instead of `debdian`?

Comment: @DefSoudani Yes it does

Comment: @Saeed It's my assignments, and I have to configure my own Dockerfile.

Comment: As @Hans Kilian said, change the `#` sign in the last two `ENTRYPOINT` lines to see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ENTRYPOINT of your MariaDB Dockerfile is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f"]
```

so it doesn't actually *run* MariaDB.

You probably need to comment that out and comment back in

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: It was temporary entrypoint to debug. When I got an error from mysql, It was `/docker-entrypoint.sh`.  I just run `mysqld` in `docker-entrypoint.sh`, so I think that it has nothing to do with my problem about ports.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about ports. I thought that each containers could communicate by just `opening` ports, but there was no `LISTEN`ing ports. Docker-compose `ports:` just binds ports and has nothing to do with `LISTEN`.

Comment: Yes, not only in `Docker`, but also in the OS if you only open ports in `iptables` or `ufw`, it does not listen to that port. There should be an application running on that port in order to work.